# Setting Rowsource property issue

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an error message every time I try to test the macro, after assigning it to a cell in my excel file.

This is what the error says: Run Time error '380'
"Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid Property Value."
I've included a screenshot of this message and a copy of my (borrowed) code below.
The strange thing is that I get zero issues when I debug the code (Compile VBA Project). However, when I try to run the macro from my excel file after assigning it, I get the error message.

```
 Option Explicit
Sub Reset()

Dim iRow As Long

iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] ' identifying the last row

With frmForm


  .txtFSA.Value = ""
  .txtCert.Value = ""
  .txtPSU.Value = ""
  .txtSelecDate.Value = ""
  .txtFRCode.Value = ""
  .txtGrade.Value = ""
  .txtPay.Value = ""
  .txtTrackOut.Value = ""
  .txtTrackIN.Value = ""
  .txtNHPDate = ""
  
  .txtName.Value = ""
  .txtLastName.Value = ""
  .OptMale.Value = False
  .OptFemale.Value = False
  .txtDOB.Value = ""
  .txtPhone.Value = ""
  .txtEmail.Value = ""
  .txtAddress.Value = ""
  .txtCity.Value = ""
  .txtZip.Value = ""
  .txtState.Value = ""
  
  .CmbSurvey.Clear
  
  .CmbSurvey.AddItem "AHS"
  .CmbSurvey.AddItem "CPS"
  .CmbSurvey.AddItem "SIPP"
  .CmbSurvey.AddItem "NIHS"
  
  .LstDatabase.ColumnCount = 24
  .LstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
  
 ' .LstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "75 pt; 0pt"
 
  
  If iRow > 1 Then
  
    .LstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:X" & iRow
  
  Else
  .LstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:X2"
  
  End If
  


End With


End Sub



Sub Submit()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long



Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")


iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1

With sh
    .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1
    
     .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.CmbSurvey
     .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtFSA
     .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.txtCert
     .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.txtPSU
     .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.txtSelecDate
     .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.txtName
     .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.txtLastName
     .Cells(iRow, 9) = IIf(frmForm.OptFemale.Value = True, "Female", "Male")
     .Cells(iRow, 10) = frmForm.txtDOB
     .Cells(iRow, 11) = frmForm.txtAddress
     .Cells(iRow, 12) = frmForm.txtCity
     .Cells(iRow, 13) = frmForm.txtZip
     .Cells(iRow, 14) = frmForm.txtState
     .Cells(iRow, 15) = frmForm.txtPhone
     .Cells(iRow, 16) = frmForm.txtEmail
     .Cells(iRow, 17) = frmForm.txtFRCode
     .Cells(iRow, 18) = frmForm.txtGrade
     .Cells(iRow, 19) = frmForm.txtPay
     .Cells(iRow, 20) = frmForm.txtNHPDate
     .Cells(iRow, 21) = frmForm.txtTrackOut
     .Cells(iRow, 22) = frmForm.txtTrackIN
     .Cells(iRow, 23) = Application.UserName
     .Cells(iRow, 24) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY-HH:MM:SS")]

End With

End Sub


Sub Show_Form()

  
    frmForm.Show
  



End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I presume it's the typo ("Lst..." instead of "List...") in `.LstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:X2"`.  I recommend to avoid the repetition. Try `If iRow < 2 Then iRow = 2`: `.LstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:X" & iRow`.

Comment: I labeled the second frame LstDatabase as an abbreviation. 
I didn’t get any errors while debugging the code though... that’s why I’m really lost.

Comment: A `Frame` doesn't have a `RowSource` property, a ListBox` does. What's the point of assigning a source to a ListBox if there are row and to a Frame if there are none?

Comment: I apologize! 
It’s a list box within a frame.

Comment: You may have to address the list box differently, like *frmForm.Frame.ListBox* instead of the simple *frmForm.ListBox* you use.